# windows 10 localhost resolution slow

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-10, localhost, hosts-file

i am running a local python server on windows 10 and sending requests to it via the `localhost` domain are significantly slower than using `127.0.0.1`. i have edited my hosts file and the problem occurs whether i have `127.0.0.1    localhost` commented out or not (including ipv6 entry). if i use any other domain with an entry in my hosts file pointing to `127.0.0.1` then the problem goes away which proves that the hosts file is working correctly for all custom entries. i have tried flushing dns and various other commands to clear out any DNS caching to no avail.

even though `localhost` is defined in my functioning hosts file something is specifically hijacking the domain resolution and causing it to respond much slower than it should.

i realize there have been a number of posts about this issue but they all simply suggest using `127.0.0.1` instead which does not solve the problem or explain why it is happening.

Comment: You may take a look at https://superuser.com/questions/436574/ipv4-vs-ipv6-priority-in-windows-7/436944#436944, which solves my problem perfectly.